# match everything until parenthesis

Tags: regex, r

Given a string `str = "Senior Software Engineer (mountain view)"`

How can I match everything until I hit the first parenthesis, giving me back "Senior Software Engineer"

Comment: Plain regex: `^[^(]+`, `r` implementation I leave up to others...

Comment: Don't edit your titles with things like "[answered]". That's what the check mark next to answers is for. Use them!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you would use `^[^\(]+` to match that and then trim it to remove the trailing space

Comment: it works! specifically regmatches(str, regexpr("^[^\\(]+", str))[[1]];

Comment: Why is the first `^` necessary?

Comment: @Swadq it matches the beginning of a line. Without it you would also match everything after the `(`

Comment: Ah yes, indeed ^^ I'll edit my answer so as not to confuse later readers

Answer (score 8):

`^[^\(]*`

`[^\(]` is a character class, which matches everything except for `(`, and `*` is a greedy match, which matches the class as many times as possible. The `^` at the beginning matches from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the trailing whitespace, try `^.*?(?=\s\()`.

`^(.*?)` tells it to match as few characters as possible, from the start of the string, and the `(?=\s\()` anchors the other end of the match to your paren, without capturing it or the whitespace before it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this simple regex in R: `*\\(.*`

```
str <- "Senior Software Engineer (mountain view)"

sub(" *\\(.*", "", str)
# [1] "Senior Software Engineer"
```

It also avoids the trailing whitespace.

Comment: error: sub is not defined

Answer (score 1):

and if you wanna match everything until and after parenthesis, try this:

SEARCH:  `^[^\(]+|(\)).*`

REPLACE BY:  `\1`

and if you want to match all paranthesis and delete them, try this:

SEARCH: `\([^(\r\n]*?\)|\(|\)`

REPLACE BY:  `(LEAVE EMPTY)`

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse way...

```
library("stringr")
```

> The output of below, will return you list...

```
str_match_all(str, "^[^\\(]+")
```

> If you need in string

```
str_match_all(str, "^[^\\(]+") %>% toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The package *unglue* offers a readable alternative :

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)

x <- "Senior Software Engineer (mountain view)"
unglue_vec(x,"{job} ({location})", var = "job")
#> [1] "Senior Software Engineer"
```

More info: https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue/blob/master/README.md